# Splitting one commit into 2 and get the resulting diff

Tags: git, review-board

I recently posted a diff to review board at work. I didn't really check the diff until after and I noticed that whitespace at the end of lines was removed by my editor. I'd like to split those whitespace changes out into a separate commit. How can I do this?

Afterward, I think the easiest way to update the diff would be to actually just upload the diff. There have been a bunch of commits since my commit and I've rebased since (we always pull --rebase here) so just updating review board using the guess features might not work out really.

Note: I've already pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with "review board," but here's a general git strategy for answering this part of the question:

> I'd like to split those whitespace changes out into a separate commit. What would be the easiest way to do this.

```
git checkout whitespace-fix
git reset --hard <sha of commit you posted diff of>
git reset HEAD~1
git add --patch .
```

Now stage the hunks that correspond to the whitespace issues (tip: use "s" to split presented hunks into smaller hunks).  After you're done, commit and rebase and your fresh commit is ready.

```
git commit -m 'Remove whitespace at end of lines'
git rebase master
```

Comment: I think this is a valid solution. I'm going to modify it a bit somehow (if you have ideas I'd love to hear them). A big problem is that I pushed to master. So I'd be playing with a commit in other people's history which is generally bad news. Perhaps I'll revert the change, then just "redo it" using this method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, to solve the **current** situation, meaning - *getting to have in Review Board the diff containing only your relevant changes (and not the space changes)* - **the easiest  thing** to do would be this:

1. **re-create the diff based on the revision numbers** you got after
   pushing *(like this, you ensure you have no relative paths issues
   when uploading the diff again to Review Board)*;
2. **clean the diff by editing it** and keep only the relevant changes *(depending on the
   size of the diff, you have a few choices to go with - simple
   select/remove or smart search & replace, reg. exp., etc)*;
3. **upload your diff again** *(if you want to use the same review request, use the
   Update Diff feature, otherwise, simply create a new review
   request)*.

These should fix the trouble.

*On the other hand...*

I guess you should solve the part with getting those spaces in the diff files you are creating - this makes a pain to review changes when you're looking at the history of code modifications.
Here, you could have quite a few things check, like the diff command that you are using.

I hope this helps!